# Theorem 3.6.4 in Michael Potter's Set Theory and Its Philosophy

Tags: logic, set-theory

I am reading Michael Potter's Set Theory and Its Philosophy self-taught.
Theorem 3.6.4 has me at a loss.

First, I am having trouble translating what the theorem says into a formula.
The theorem states that if $\mathcal{V}$ is a *history* and $a$ is a non-*empty* *subcollection* of $\mathcal{V}$, then there is a member of $a$ that is *disjoint* from it.
Does this mean $\forall \mathcal{V}, (\mathcal{V}\text{ is history}) \to \forall a, (a\text{ is collection})\text{ and }(\text{not }(a\text{ is empty}))\text{ and }a \subseteq \mathcal{V} \to \exists x, x \in a\text{ and }(x\text{ is disjoint from }a)$?
Note that there are definitions in the book for each of history, collection, empty, $\subseteq$, and disjoint.

Next, the first sentence of the proof states that suppose on the contrary that $a$ has no $\in$-minimal member.
I am not sure what this assumes.
I don't think $\in$-minimal member is defined in the book.
If this is a proof by contradiction, does it mean that it is $\text{not }\exists x, x \in a\text{ and }(x\text{ is disjoint from }a)$?

In the second sentence of the proof it is stated that $\bigcap a = \{x : (\forall b \in a)(x \in b)\}$ exists by the axiom scheme of separation.
However, in chapter 3.5 the axiom scheme of separation is defined as $(\forall V)(\{x \in V : \Phi(x)\}\text{ exists})$, and $V$ represents a level (by chapter 3.4).
Thus, to use the axiom of separation I should have to have a level, but there is no level in the assumptions of the theorem.

In summary, these are three things I am struggling with: translation of the theorem into a formula, translation of the first sentence of the proof into a formula, and justification of the second sentence of the proof.
Could someone please help me with these?

---

The following is a presentation of a self-contained Potter's collection theory.
The collection theory is based on first-order logic with identity, definite description operator $℩!$, unary relation $U$ and binary relation $\in$.

$℩!x\Phi(x)$ is read ‘the $x$ such that $\Phi(x)$’.
Expressions of this form are called *definite descriptions*.
Definite descriptions do not always refer to some object, e.g. $℩!x(x \neq x)$.
$℩!x\Phi(x)$ exists if $(\exists x)(\forall y)(\Phi(y) \leftrightarrow x = y)$.
$\sigma = \tau$ is read ‘if one of $\sigma$ and $\tau$ exists, then they both exist and they are equal’.

$U(x)$ is read ‘$x$ is urelemente’.
$x \in y$ is read ‘$x$ belongs to $y$’.

$℩!y(\text{not }U(y)\text{ and }(\forall x)(x \in y \leftrightarrow \Phi(x)))$ is abbreviated $\{x : \Phi(x)\}$.
$(\forall x)(x \in a \to x \in b)$ is abbreviated $a \subseteq b$.

$a$ is *collection* if $a = \{x : x \in a\}$.
Extensionality of collection is not an axiom in this theory, but a theorem.

A collection $a$ is *empty* if $(\forall x)(x \notin a)$.
$\bigcap a \overset{\text{def}}{=} \{x : (\forall b \in a)(x \in b)\}$.
$\{a, b\} \overset{\text{def}}{=} \{x : x = a\text{ or }x = b\}$.
$a \cap b \overset{\text{def}}{=} \bigcap \{a, b\}$.
Two collections $a$ and $b$ are *disjoint* if they have no members in common.

$\mathrm{acc}(a) \overset{\text{def}}{=} \{x : U(x)\text{ or }(\exists b \in a)(x \in b\text{ or }x \subseteq b)\}$.
$\mathrm{acc}(a)$ is read ‘the accumulation of $a$’.
$\mathcal{V}$ is called a *history* if $(\forall V \in \mathcal{V})(V = \mathrm{acc}(\mathcal{V} \cap V))$.
The accumulation of a history is called a *level*.

*Axiom scheme of separation*: For every level $V$, $\{x \in V : \Phi(x)\}$ exists.

Comment: Potter's presentation is not a standard presentation of  ZFC, which is fine - I could guess what the terms mean. But, i'd rather not. Can you define what a History is, and what a level is? Also, I'm assuming a subcollection/collection and subset are the same thing, although how you talk about them makes me feel they might not be in Potter's presentation.

Comment: The issue of ∈-minimal member regards the [Axiom of regularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity). the assumption that $a$ has no "minimal..." means that there is an infinite descending sequence of sets and this is equivalent to say that every non-empty set contains an element that is disjoint from it.

Comment: An *history* is a collection and - I think - [every collection has an accumulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott%E2%80%93Potter_set_theory)) because an accumulation is made of *urelemets* plus... Thus, every history must have an accumulation.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestive comments.It seems clear that the author has the axiom of regularity in mind here.  
By the way, I don't think it follows that every collection has its accumulation.

Comment: Suppose, for example, that we adopt as axioms the axiom scheme of separation and the existence of an empty collection. By the collection extensionality theorem, it would be easy to show that empty collections are unique. Since the empty collection has no members, it is vacuously true that this is a history, but its accumulation is a comprehension of all urelements. However, it seems non-trivial in the axioms we have adopted that this is a collection. (Because we don't even have the axiom of pairing at this point.)